# Source files not displaying in Visual Studio for System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I've downloaded the System.Data.Sqlite source code (Version 1.0.0.102) and want to build it in Visual Studio 2013.

For some reason all the C# projects show no files. I can see in each project file lines similar to -

```
< Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Targets\System.Data.SQLite.Files.targets" / >
```

which I guess should add the files into the project but it doesn't seem to. The .targets file is found and contains a list of all the files.

How can I get the files to appear so I can build the solution?

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: System.Data.SQLite is built in Visual C++ not C#.

Comment: System.Data.SQLite is C# built in Visual Studio, not C++.
There is C++ interop to the Sqlite library which System.Data.SQLite uses but this is also built in Visual Studio. 
Are you thinking of the Sqlite library itself rather than System.Data.SQLite?

Comment: No, there is no C#. The `sqlite.dll` (or `SQLite.Interop.dll`) is compiled in unmanaged C++, then there is a `System.Data.SQLite.dll`, compiled in managed C++, which is MSIL, so you can use it within your C# project.

Comment: System.Data.SQLite is C#. You are right about sqlite.dll and sqlite.interop.dll but not System.Data.SQLite. 

See a screenshot from my Visual Studio:
http://imgur.com/jTAjICG

As you can see System.Data.Sqlite project contains multiple C# files. Next to the project is 'C#' indicating that it is C#. In the project properties shown it shows that is compiled against .net 4.5.1 and outputs as a C# dll class library. It uses sqlite.interop.dll and sqlite.dll but the system.data.sqlite C# project is C#.

Anyway, this is besides the point - I am looking for an answer to my original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I could find was to manually merge in the contents of each .targets file into each project file using a text editor.

I found on the System.Data.Sqlite FAQ's page (https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki) they mention that due to limitations in Visual Studio the files won't show up but will still build correctly.

I however wanted to actually see and step through the source code. It was a bit tedious to merge but seemed to work fine. Shame there's not a way for Visual Studio handle it.